# problem regarding theory of equations

Tags: roots

given quadratic equation : ${x^2+bx+c=0}$

let the roots of the equation be ${u}$ and $v$.

let ${S_0 = u^0+v^0}$

let ${S_1 = u^1+v^1}$

let ${S_2 = u^2+v^2}$

show that :  ${S_2+bS_1+S_0 = 0}$

Comment: Please see the correction at your question

Answer (score 1):

See, 
${S_0 = 1 +1=2}$ and ${S_1 =  u+ v}$ but ${u +v}$ is the sum of roots and hence ${ S_1=u + v = -b}$.
Now, ${ (u+v)^2 = u^2 + v^2 + 2uv}$ is equivalent to $(S_1)^2 = S_2 + 2\text{(product of roots)}$. And $\text{product of roots} = c$. Now put the appropriate values into the equations. You should get your solution. :))

Comment: have tried that . but instead iam left with 2(1-c)

Comment: I think you should re-check the question because ${S_2 + bS_1 + S_0=0}$ is only possible only when ${c=1}$. So, I think the question is wrong! :)